# SSL's phpMyAdmin page 404 Not Found [Nginx + Centos7.5]

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, centos

I'm studying Nginx. I would like to ask about phpMyAdmin with SSL.
I did Cerbot SSL with 2 static domain. and I can access phpMyAdmin.
as http://mywebiste.com/phpMyAdmin/
However whenI open https://mywebiste.com/phpMyAdmin/
error says

> 404 Not Found.

I had been searching error log. but I still don't know how to set up log at pma so I can't see it.
Could you teach me write setting code please?

Here is my current setting file.

> vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf

```
server {
       #listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebiste.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebiste.com/privkey.pem;


       server_name  mywebiste.com/phpmyadmin;

       location / {
                root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin;
                index index.php;
                }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/$fastcgi_scr
ipt_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use uri link in `server_name` variable. This variable needed only for domain name, without `http`, `https`, `/` or another symbols.

I changed your config a little:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebiste.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebiste.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebiste.com/privkey.pem;

    root /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

In this case you opening a PhpMyAdmin if use URL `https://mywebiste.com` or `https://mywebiste.com/index.php`.

If you need this URL `https://mywebiste.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php` change variable `root` in `location /`. Also it is possible to use a separate location, example in [67349181](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67349181/phpmyadmin-502-bad-gateway-centos7-nginx) question.

You can validate the configuration with `nginx -t` command. Problem will be always written to the error log, by default `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

Say if you need more information.

Comment: Dear @qwsj Thank you for helping me again. I appreciate. I tried your code. but I got 404 error that says failed (2: No such file or directory) And [warn]  conflicting server name "mywebsite.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored . .and I tried to open http link it become 404 error too.

Comment: @blueink sry, my bad. I updated config.
About: `And [warn] conflicting server name "mywebsite.com" on 0.0.0.0:443`
Check full configuration via `nginx -T`, maybe you have a duplicate for `listen 443 ssl;` and `server_name mywebiste.com;`.

Comment: Dear @qwsj Thank you again. I tried your new answer however when I hit http the result is same 404. And Hit https ,502 Bad Gateway error show up. I did nginx -T so message says nginx.conf syntax is ok　and test is successful
and still same [warn] 8341#8341: conflicting server name "mywebiste.con" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

Comment: @blueink You probably have duplicate config, because you could get a problem. Command `nginx -T` (uppercase T) print all active configs.
More than one host with identical `listen` its normal, but domain in `server_name` should not be repeated with identical `listen`, even if they are in different configs.
Code 502 means that the communication problem between nginx and php-fpm (this code usually occurs if the socket is not available - fpm stopped, permission problem, socket is not exist).

Comment: Dear @qwsj Thank you. I read your comment and I've tried to fix that. but its very hard for me the result are not change.
I did 2 vertual domain setting in those files that's why my confing messed up. 
I did nginx -T and here is my whole code. Could you take a look please? 
https://justpaste.it/7vc5p

Comment: @blueink You have a configs inside nginx.conf, but its bad practice, you already have include `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. Use this path for virtual hosts. Check this configs: https://pastebin.com/HxsEvEdq

Comment: Dear @qwsj Thank you again. as you taught me I cleaned my code sorry I did little by little so took long time. I can display SSL index.html pages at 2 domains but still phpmyadmin pages says 404 and 502 error. Here is my current whole code. https://justpaste.it/3avhy Could you take a look pleaes?

Comment: @blueink Show me nginx error.log at the moment of the problem. PhpMyAdmin files exist in `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin`?

Comment: Dear @qwsj Sorry for late. I paste my error log at here Please take a look update, And Yes. . PhpMyAdmin files exist in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin.